# Intent-filter to match domain only (no path)

Tags: android, android-manifest, intentfilter

This might seem simple, but I can't figure out how to do it yet.

I need my app to be opened when user click on domain url.
I need to match the URL with domain (android:host) without path.
example.com or example.com/

I get it to work on example.com/ (with slash), but I can't capture the URL without slash: example.com

I tried using pathPattern /*, it doesn't work too.

Below is my Android Manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data android:scheme="http" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />

    <data android:host="example.com" />
    <data android:host="www.example.com" />

    <data android:pathPattern="/*" />
    <data android:path="/" />
</intent-filter>
```

Simply say, I wish match the URL with or without ending slash "/".
http://example.com
http://example.com/

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio's URL Mapping Editor was misleading for me. It said that https://example.org/anypath would map to MainActivity with the following configuration but it wasn't true in practice. Only https://example.org/ mapped to the MainActivity

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data
        android:host="www.example.org"
        android:path="/"
        android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score -1):

you do not need multiple data tags, you only need one for this case. Each data tag can have a scheme, host, path, path pattern and so on. If there is no scheme, the rest is ignored. If there is no host (but a scheme), the path attributes are ignored. The correct way to do what you want is

`<data android:scheme="http" android:host="example.com" />`

and this is all you should need. [Docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html)

Comment: This doesn't work. With no path argument, only `http://example.com/` is matched, not `http://example.com` (testing via `adb shell start`)